# What's the difference, if any, between stock appreciation and compound interest?

Tags: investing, yield

I'm trying to estimate what the returns for a 9% stock appreciation and a 6% dividend reinvestment investment portfolio would look like and I've read compounding isn't the same as dividend reinvestment so I'm also having problems using the dividend calculators because their more precise then in general terms and I don't know if stock appreciation is simple interest or compound interest. I'd also like to know what sort of return I'd see after I factor in risks, taxes, inflation, and management.

Comment: Stocks and interest-bearing assets are fundamentally different things.

Comment: If your figures are effective annual yield the effective return would be 15%.

Comment: Man, that is one heck of a run-on sentence.

Comment: Do you want to take _taxes_ on the investment into account in the comparison, or are they a separate issue that you cannot be bothered with right now?

Answer (score 2):

Compounding is just the notion that the current period's growth (or loss) becomes the next period's principal. So, applied to stocks, your beginning value, plus growth (or loss) in value, plus any dividends, becomes the beginning value for the next period. Your value is compounded as you measure the performance of the investment over time. Dividends do not participate in the compounding unless you reinvest them.

Compound interest is just the principle of compounding applied to an amount owed, either by you, or to you. You have a balance with which a certain percentage is calculated each period and is added to the balance. The new balance is used to calculate the next period's interest, which again adds to the balance, etc. Obviously, it's better to be on the receiving end of a compound interest calculation than on the paying end.

Interest bearing investments, like bonds, pay simple interest. Like stock dividends, you would have to invest the interest in something else in order to get a compounding effect.

When using a basic calculator tool for stocks, you would include the expected average annual growth rate plus the expected annual dividend rate as your "interest" rate. For bonds you would use the coupon rate plus the expected rate of return on whatever you put the interest into as the "interest" rate.

Factoring in risk, you would just have to pick a different rate for a simple calculator, or use a more complex tool that allows for more variables over time. Believe it or not, this is where you would start seeing all that calculus homework pay off!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, If I invest, say, $1000 in a stock that is growing at 5% per year, versus investing $1000 in an account that pays compound interest of 5% per year, how does the amount I have after 5 years compare? Then the answer is, They would be exactly the same.

As Kent Anderson says, "compound interest" simply means that as you accumulate interest, that for the next interest cycle, the amount that they pay interest on is based on the previous cycle balance PLUS the interest. For example, suppose you invest $1000 at 5% interest compounded annually. After one year you get 5% of $1000, or $50. You now have $1050. At the end of the second year, you get 5% of $1050 -- not 5% of the original $1000 -- or $52.50, so you now have $1102.50. Etc.

Stocks tend to grow in the same way.

But here's the big difference: If you get an interest-bearing account, the bank or investment company guarantees the interest rate. Unless they go bankrupt, you WILL get that percentage interest. But there is absolutely no guarantee when you buy stock. It may go up 5% this year, up 4% next year, and down 3% the year after. The company makes no promises about how much growth the stock will show. It may show a loss. It all depends on how well the company does.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The title asks about the difference between stock growth and compound interest, and that is what I attempted to answer. I interpreted the references to "stock appreciation" and "dividend reinvestment" to both be scenario 1, with scenario 2 being compound interest. If the poster's intent was to ask about the difference between stock appreciation and dividend reinvestment, then neither of those is "compound interest" or any other sort of interest, so a contrast between the two is not between compound interest and anything else.